# set array indexes many at once? compound literals?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

```
index = {27,27,27,27,27}; //as many as rootsize
```

Compiler gives me an error when I try this in a function. Index is globally initialized in the same file with:

```
int index[5];
```

error: expected expression
        index = {27,27,27,27,27}; //as many as rootsize

Is this not legal? How would I set an array to some values all at once?  Would I need a loop?

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages.

Comment: C but I'm learning both and open to C++ advice

Comment: Learn one and only one first. In spite of the common root, the two languages are very different concerning details.

Comment: In the current version of C++, this is not a syntax error, but still a semantic error for built-in array types. It is perfectly valid for several container types, including `std::array<int, 5>` and `std::vector<int>`. This probably would've been better to ask for C and for C++ separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly assign to an array.  You can, however, `memcpy()` to it from a compound literal:

```
#include <string.h>

memcpy(index, (int [5]){ 27, 27, 27, 27, 27 }, sizeof index);
```

Note that compound literals like this are a C feature, but not C++.

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize array as you are doing it because array name can't be a modifiable lvalue in C.

```
int index[5] = {27,27,27,27,27};
```

is a valid initialization

Comment: I see.  Would it be faster to initialize a new array in the function or set the indexes of a global array 1 by 1?

Comment: I believe it would be roughly the same - both methods require setting a value to each of the array indices. Only global array default initialisation is done at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Just write `int index[5] = {27,27,27,27,27}`. and your problem resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can use standard class `std::array` declared in header `<array>`.

For example

```
#include <array>

//...

std::array<int, 5> index;

//...

index = { 27, 27, 27, 27, 27 };
```

Otherwise you can use for example standard algorithms `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` declared in header `<algorithm>` to fill the array with a value.

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

int index[5];

//...

std::fill( std::begin( index ), std::end( index ), 27 );
// or
std::fill( index, index + 5, 27 );
```

Or

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

int index[5];

//...

std::fill_n( index, 5, 27 );
```

In C you can also enclose the array in a structure and use a compound literal. For example

```
struct array_t 
{ 
    int index[5]; 
} a;

//...

a = ( struct array_t ){ { 27, 27, 27, 27, 27 } };   

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) printf( "%i ", a.index[i] );
```

Of course you can initialize the array when it was declared

```
int index[5] = { 27, 27, 27, 27, 27 };
```